# How to replace string in Dart with replace string pattern

Tags: dart

In C# or javascript with regex, I could description a replace pattern as a string like this:

```
var replaced = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "$1AA$3");
```

In dart, the replace part is a function

```
final newString = string.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'\b\w+\b'), (match) {
  return '"${match.group(0)}"';
});
```

The problem is that, I want to write a util function, receive strReplacePattern as a string

```
Utils.replace(inputText, strPattern, strReplacePattern) { ... }
```

coder will simple input the replace part as a string pattern, dont neeed provide a match/replace function, how to implement like that in dart.

I want the replace part is a string pattern, not a callback function.

Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of using this method and the expected output?

Comment: var res = Utils.replace('the 2020 end', '(\d+)', '$1 year');

expected: the 2020 year end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to find any package which provides such functionality. But you could try make your own like this:

```
void main() {
  final result = Utils.replace('the 2020 end', r'(\d+)', r'$1 year');
  print(result); // the 2020 year end
}

class Utils {
  static String replace(
          String inputText, String pattern, String strReplacePattern) =>
      inputText.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(pattern), (match) {
        var replacedString = strReplacePattern;
        for (var i = 0; i <= match.groupCount; i++) {
          replacedString = replacedString.replaceAll('\$$i', match.group(i)!);
        }
        return replacedString;
      });
}
```

It should be noted it is rather basic (e.g. no escaping of replacing $1) and does properly not work entirely like the one from C# and/or JavaScript. But it was the best I could come up with right now.